# Bash pass typed yes to EasyRSA gen-req

Tags: bash

**Problem:** I'm trying to script an EasyRSA key gen request, but, if the key file already exists, any attempt to overwrite using `yes` or `echo yes` commands result in `Aborting without confirmation`. I believe EasyRSA is requiring me to actually type 'yes' and anything else results in an abort.

I'm wondering if there's another way to pass 'yes' to a prompt that requires a typed response?

**What I've tried:** `yes | <command>`, `yes yes | <command>` and `echo yes | <command>`

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked for me: `echo yes | ./easyrsa revoke certificate.name`

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things. First one might not work but second would.

First: You can execute easyrsa by

```
pi@raspberry$ sudo easyrsa <some command> -y
```

The -y will force it to do yes. You can alternatively use -yes or -f arguments too. If this doesn't work, try the second method.

```
pi@raspberry$ sudo ./script.sh
```

The script will contain this:

```
cat << EOF | sudo easyrsa <some command>
yes
EOF
```

This will definitely work. Glad to help :)

Comment: do let me know of the results so I can further modify my answer and help you further

Comment: First two didn't work. Trying the second. I suppose if the key already exists, I dont really need to remake it and I could give myself an argument to wait for my response to the prompt.

Comment: I only wrote two methods? By the way did you execute `sudo ./script` and did you execute this before making the script?

Comment: I'm getting an `unexpected end of file` error. The script wasn't made with sudo.

`if [ -f "pki/private/$name.key" ]; then
        cat << EOF | sudo ./easyrsa gen-req $name nopass
        yes
        EOF
fi`

Comment: you need to get your indent right in ending EOF. the indent might be causing issue. The last EOF before fi needs to have zero indent i think. Try changing its indent and try again. It will solve your problem

Comment: When I try "easyrsa build-client-full xxx nopass -y" with easyrsa v3.1.6 it prints "Ignoring unknown command option: '-y'"

Answer (score 1):

This ain't all of it (?),  but a part that works creating new key or whether to overwrite existing key or not ,

```
#client common name - a string
CN=$1

# 'yes' or 'no' to overwrite or not resp.
OVERWRITE=$2 

#paths
EASYRSA_DIR="/path/to/easy-rsa/easyrsa3"
EASYRSA="./easyrsa"

if [ -f "$EASYRSA_DIR/pki/private/$CN.key" ]; then         
    cat <<-EOF  | sudo $EASYRSA gen-req $CN nopass         
    $OVERWRITE
    $CN
    EOF
else
    cat <<-EOF  | sudo $EASYRSA gen-req $CN nopass         
    $CN   
    EOF
fi
```

then run the script with further commands to satisfy easy-rsa!
Expected output:

```
Note: using Easy-RSA configuration from: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/vars
Using SSL: openssl OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020


WARNING!!!

An existing private key was found at /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/pki/private/testuser.key
Continuing with key generation will replace this key.

Type the word 'yes' to continue, or any other input to abort.
  Confirm key overwrite: Generating a RSA private key
............................+++++
.....................+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/pki/easy-rsa-12805.EocLO7/tmp.CmRehr'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Common Name (eg: your user, host, or server name) [testuser]:
Keypair and certificate request completed. Your files are:
req: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/pki/reqs/testuser.req
key: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/pki/private/testuser.key
```